# Convert MyISAM to InnoDB database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb, myisam

I'm trying to convert a whole database from MyISAM to InnoDB with this statement:

```
use information_schema;

SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' ENGINE=InnoDB;') 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE engine = "MyISAM" AND table_type = "BASE TABLE" AND table_schema = "database";
```

and while I get a result that every table is changed for example:

```
ALTER TABLE database.action ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

when I check the table engines they're still MyISAM. The weird thing is that if I run the command separately

```
ALTER TABLE action ENGINE='InnoDB';
```

it works fine for that table.

Any tips on how to do the conversion for the whole database?

Comment: I usually just mark this up in a text editor and run it. Trying to do it in pure SQL is an exercise in frustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SELECT statement you are running only generates strings; the strings it generates are not being executed as SQL statements. You'd need to take the resultset from that query, and then actually execute those statements as a separate step.

Comment: You are right I found the same thing 5 mins later. Thanks for your response! Just to clarify, there's no way to run them all in a single command right? Like pipe in Linux?

Comment: @geolykos: No, there's no way to run them in a single SQL statement. Each row from the resultset in your query needs to be executed as a statement. For a one time shot, just save the result set as a text file. You could write a small application, or even a MySQL stored program (procedure), to loop through the resultset and execute a separate statement for each row returned.